# Building Unity from Batch file using Node.js

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, command-line, build, automation

I have my the command working when i type it into a regular command prompt. But when i run the command from a batch file using Node.js (child_process) i get a error. I compared the the log files and I got this error.

```
ArgumentException: Key duplication when adding: PATH
at System.Collections.Hashtable.PutImpl (System.Object key, System.Object value, Boolean overwrite) [0x00137] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs:831
at System.Collections.Hashtable.Add (System.Object key, System.Object value) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs:474
at System.Collections.Specialized.ProcessStringDictionary.Add (System.String key, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.get_EnvironmentVariables () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at UnityEditor.WebGL.Emscripten.EmccArguments.SetEnvironmentVariable (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.String environmentVariable, System.String value) [0x0001f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/Emscripten/EmccArguments.cs:32
at UnityEditor.WebGL.Emscripten.EmccArguments.SetupDefaultEmscriptenEnvironment (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00011] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/Emscripten/EmccArguments.cs:14
at UnityEditor.WebGL.Il2Cpp.WebGLIl2CppNativeCodeBuilder.SetupEnvironment (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00002] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/Il2Cpp/WebGLIL2CppNativeCodeBuilder.cs:102
at UnityEditorInternal.Il2CppNativeCodeBuilder.SetupStartInfo (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0000e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\Il2CppNativeCodeBuilder.cs:109
at UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo) [0x00034] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\BuildUtils.cs:64
at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 arguments, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) [0x0008b] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:380
at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (ICollection`1 userAssemblies, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) [0x002dc] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:361
at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () [0x00099] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:178
at UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) [0x0001d] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\Il2Cpp\IL2CPPUtils.cs:42
at UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.CompileBuild (BuildPostProcessArgs args) [0x000fb] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:367
at UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) [0x002de] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:936
at UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) [0x00003] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\Modules\DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:27
at UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) [0x000d9] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:287
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions, Boolean)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternal(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:359)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:254)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:237)
LGDBuildScript:BuildWebProject() (at Assets\Editor\LGDBuildScript.cs:16)

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Hashtable.cs Line: 831)
```

I have read all of the child_process documentation and Unity Command Line Arguments documentation and i still can't figure it out.

I'm hoping to have the Unity.exe build my game from my Node.js app.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: @derHugo 

The command looks like Unity.exe -batchmode -quit -na -projectpath "./project" -executeMethod Builder.BuildForWeb

It works when i call the command by itself. It causes a problem when i call the command from node.js.

Comment: Did you try to use the complete system path instead of the relative one `./project`? Usually the console opens in your users "home" directory but the node server runs in a different folder.

Comment: @derHugo I just wrote an example of what the path looks like. It actually points to the correct unity.ex path and project path. The command builds Unity when i run it outside of the node environment.

Comment: Yes as I said when you run that command you run it from a shell/console which has certain predefined [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment so it "knows" where to look for things. Apparently your node environment has those `PATH` environment variables configured wrong or as the error states it can't add a `PATH` environment variable because it already exists.

Comment: @derHugo You were right i ended up passing the env variables when i started the cmd from Node. 

child_process.exec('cmd /c ' + 'games\\' + projectName + 'WebDeploy.bat',{ 
        silent: false,
      }
 to 
child_process.exec('cmd /c ' + 'games\\' + projectName + 'WebDeploy.bat',{ 
        silent: false,
        cwd: process.cwd(),
        env: {
            PATH: process.env.PATH
        } 
      }